# How to do Pandas data frame comparison on one column, row by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets consider two data frames

```
df1=
 A    B    C   D  E    F  G
 a1   b1  c1  d1  e1  f1  1
 a2   b2  c2  d2  e2  f2  3
 a3   b3  c3  d3  e3  f2  5
 a4   b4  c4  d4  e4  f4  Nan

df2=
 A    B    C   D  E    F  G
 a1   b1  c1  d1  e1  f1  1
 a2   b2  c2  d2  e2  f2  3
 a3   b3  c3  d3  e3  f2  4
 a4   b4  c4  d4  e4  f4  Nan
 a5   b5  c5  d5  e5  f5  7
```

I want to compare the two dataframes on the  column G, but we should do it only if each row in each dataframe as same value., So from A to F, if each row is same in df1 and df2 generate a column called result which shows column G from df1 - column G from df2 to yield a dataframe  like this.

```
resultdf=
 A    B    C   D  E    F G_DF1 G_DF2  Result
 a1   b1  c1  d1  e1  f1   1     1     0
 a2   b2  c2  d2  e2  f2   3     3     0
 a3   b3  c3  d3  e3  f2   5     4     1
 a4   b4  c4  d4  e4  f4  Nan    Nan   Nan
```

The row number 5 in df2 should be discarded.

I tried

```
result=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[A,B,C,D,E,F]) but it doesn't seem to work.
```

Comment: Why did row 1 and 2 get value `0` in the result?

Comment: result row G_DF1 -G_DF2

Comment: Then the third row should be `1`? `5-4`

Comment: my bad, someone had change the question format after I made edits.

Comment: Oh it's my fault, sorry about that.

Comment: The third row should actually be `-1` now I look at it `4-5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we get the column names in a generalized way without hardcoding it with `iloc` and `tolist`. Then we `merge` on these columns. Finally we `assign` your `Result` column and `drop` the `G` columns:

```
cols = [col for col in df2.columns if col != 'G']
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on=cols)
df2.assign(Result=df2['G_y'] - df2['G_x']).drop(columns=['G_x', 'G_y'])
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F  Result
0  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1     0.0
1  a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  f2     0.0
2  a3  b3  c3  d3  e3  f2     1.0
3  a4  b4  c4  d4  e4  f4     NaN
```

---

Or we can do this in a one liner with `apply`, but this would not be my preferred solution:

```
cols = [col for col in df2.columns if col != 'G']

df2.set_index(cols).merge(df1.set_index(cols), 
                          left_index=True,
                          right_index=True).apply(lambda x: x['G_x'] - x['G_y'], axis=1)\
                                           .reset_index(name="Result")
```

Comment: does the order of the columns matter? in this case? what df1 has rows 'D A B C E F G' as opposed to the normal order?

Comment: No it does not matter. As long as the `G` column is the last column

Comment: what if  the G column isn't the last column? Does it make sense to then reorder the dataframes as I want and then merge?

Comment: See edit, this way we get the columns without `G` in a generalised way. This case it does not matter where `G`'s index is.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
 result = df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B','C','D','E','F'], suffixes=('_DF1','_DF2')).reset_index()
 result['Result'] = result['G_DF1'] - result['G_DF2']
```